# React Native Android Splash Screen Always On

Tags: react-native

first time setting up a React Native Splash Screen and I am having a small bug that I cannot solve.

I followed this article and I have followed it exactly (except IOS part for now) https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9

I have searched for similar issue on google etc and I have not found anyone that has anything that resembles my issue.

Here comes my addad/modified files from the article:

**Installed npm package** `npm install react-native-splash-screen --save`.

**android/app/src/main/res/drawable/background_splash.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_bg"/>
        <item
            android:width="300dp"
            android:height="300dp"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/splash_icon"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </layer-list>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Add this SplashActivity -->
    <activity
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Remove the intent-filter of the MainActivity and add a param android:exported="true" -->
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:exported="true"/>

  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

**android/app/src/main/java/[your_package_name]/SplashActivity.java**:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**android/app/src/main/java/[your_package_name]/MainActivity.java**:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

   @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           SplashScreen.show(this);
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "nameOfPackage";
  }
}
```

I have left out all the android styles files (don't think they are relevant etc). I am also not experienced at all in Android development or Java (I can read it though), which is why I'm asking this question.

**If I remove**

```
@Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           SplashScreen.show(this);
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }
```

in **MainActivity**, then the splash screens goes away when content is ready to be shown, however, then the background of the splash screen lingers for a second or two. I was told then to add this code above so that i seamlessly moves on to the content, but this is where the splash screen stays stuck, with the code above being added. I tried doing `SplashScreen.hide(this)` after onCreate, but nothing helped (again, don't know android development or java).

I appreciate your time!

Comment: You are going to use the `SplashScreen.hide()` in javascript side, not java.. When you are ready to hide the splash screen, you need to run `SplashScreen.hide()` in your component. (You also need to import SplashScreen of course `import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';`). It will not hide automatically

Comment: @UğurEren Makes sense! I am going to try that now

Comment: @UğurEren It Works! Thank you so much, that was easy then :D Make this an answer and i'll upvote it and vote it correct. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to use the `SplashScreen.hide()` in javascript side.
When you are ready to hide the splash screen, you need to run `SplashScreen.hide()` in your component.
You also need to import SplashScreen

`import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';`